# Horizontal scrollable view in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want to create a view that have the following layout:

```
       Scrollable
<----------I--------->
           V
------  ------  ------
I 1a I  I 1b I  I 1c I
------  ------  ------
------  ------  ------
I 2a I  I 2b I  I 2c I
------  ------  ------
------  ------  ------
I 3a I  I 3b I  I 3c I
------  ------  ------
```

Where the center item should be the current selection (almost like a flipped date selection). My first thought was to create three separate `UITableView:s`, but I wonder if there is a better way. My second thought was to create a `UICollectionView`. So basically, what would be the best way to achieve the above example?

Comment: So each "a" is a section of a UITableView or an indapendant view?

Comment: I was thinking separate view, or `UITableViewCell` if each row is a separate horizontal tableview (is it possible to create horizontal tableviews?). If there isn't a better way... The idea is to create a "character builder", where the top is head, middle is body and bottom is legs.

Comment: UICollectionView would be the way to go

Comment: This is precisely what `UICollectionView` was built for.

Comment: @mattjgalloway & @ColdLogic, thanks! Will go with `UICollectionView` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned UICollections way is the way to go. However you can use horizontal UITableview. I have a sample project in below link on how to create a horizontal UITableview

https://github.com/slysid/iOS/tree/master/Moviepedia

Bharath

Answer (score 1):

UICollectionView seems to be correct way to go for your layout depending on which iOS version you're targeting. So, implementing horizontal `UITableView` could be crucial. Because,`UICollectionView` is only available for >iOS 6.0.

So, if you want your app to run on device which has lower iOS 6.0, you're supposed to implement horizontal `UITableView`. Once, i've followed a nice tutorial from this [site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1).

The idea behind this, implement a `UITableView` that you can scroll on vertically. Create a custom cell that has a rotated `UITableView` as a subview.